# Difference with limit of NaNs between values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the difference (derivative) between contiguous values, for example:

```
   list   = 1,   3,   7,   6
list_diff = NaN, 2,   4,  -1
```

The case above only works when there are no NaNs in the middle of the values. In the case below, I would like to know the grade difference to see how a student's learning is evolving during time. The problem is that some grades are missing! We still want to calculate that difference (only if there are at most 2 missing grades in the middle).

How can I do this?

```
df:
      GRD1 GRD2 GRD3 GRD4 GRD5 GRD6 GRD7
001   1    6    5    9    1    7    9        
002   5    8    NaN  8'   NaN  NaN  2'         
003   7   *8*   NaN  NaN  NaN  *2*  6
```

```
df_diff:
      GRD1 GRD2 GRD3 GRD4 GRD5 GRD6 GRD7
001   NaN  5    -1   4    -8    6    2        
002   NaN  3    NaN  0    NaN  NaN  -6'         
003   NaN  1    NaN  NaN  NaN *NaN*  4
```

**See dataframe df**: Note for students 001 and 002, the differences between grades are calculated even if NaNs are in the middle because *they only have at most 2 missing grades*. E.g. `2'` - `8'` = `-6'`

However, student 003 has a gap of 3 missing grades, so, the difference in this case will not be calculated. E.g. `*2*` - `*8*` = `*NaN*`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ffill` with `limit` parameter for forward filling only 2 values before [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and then replace `0` differences by original `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.ffill(axis=1, limit=2).diff(axis=1).mask(df.isna())
print (df)
   GRD1  GRD2  GRD3  GRD4  GRD5  GRD6  GRD7
1   NaN   5.0  -1.0   4.0  -8.0   6.0   2.0
2   NaN   3.0   NaN   0.0   NaN   NaN  -6.0
3   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.ffill(axis=1, limit=2))
   GRD1  GRD2  GRD3  GRD4  GRD5  GRD6  GRD7
1   1.0   6.0   5.0   9.0   1.0   7.0   9.0
2   5.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   2.0
3   7.0   8.0   8.0   8.0   NaN   2.0   6.0

print (df.ffill(axis=1, limit=2).diff(axis=1))
   GRD1  GRD2  GRD3  GRD4  GRD5  GRD6  GRD7
1   NaN   5.0  -1.0   4.0  -8.0   6.0   2.0
2   NaN   3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  -6.0
3   NaN   1.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN   4.0
```